# ZSH: menu select autocompletion for history search

Tags: zsh

ZSH has a powerful menu select autocompletion e.g. for choosing a directory, choosing a process with kill (kill[tab][tab]). You can use arrows to navigate around the choices.

Is it possible to have the menu pop-up for the history search (CTRL+R) also? Such a way that the menu would allow the navigate the matches of current CTRL+R search bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this far from what you are asking for but it might solve your underlying issue.

There is a shell history extension that shows you a page full of results when searching history. It also shows you relevant results first based on the current directory, git repository, exit status, and host.

You can install the project here: https://github.com/curusarn/resh
Launch it using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (replaces reverse search).
This is how the search application looks like:

[image: screenshot of the search application]

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of the project and this is shameless self-promotion

Comment: This is massive. Thank you for creating this!

Answer (score 3):

`zsh-navigation-tools` does something like this. If you use oh-my-zsh you just need to add `zsh-navigation-tools` to `plugins=(...)` in your `.zshrc` then ctrl-R will give you a scrolling history with up/down and search/filtering. You can use it without oh-my-zsh but the setup looks like more work.

Answer (score 2):

1. Not that I know of.
2. *Perhaps* you wish to try `predict-on`, which does something related to what you are asking:

   ```
   autoload -U predict-on
   zle -N predict-on
   zle -N predict-off
   bindkey '^X1' predict-on
   bindkey '^X2' predict-off
   ```

Comment: Interesting function -- never heard of that one before.

Answer (score 2):

That is possible; in principle I modified the `_kill` completion to work also for history events.

Here's an example; after selecting a entry you hit [ENTER] once to accept the event number (the command line reads then f. e. `hc 780`) and hit [ENTER] again to execute the command. (Use `fc` instead of `hc` if you want to modify the command line prior to execution).

```
$ hc Makefile[TAB]
history event
 1906  9.3.2013 18:10  vi Makefile
 1867  9.3.2013 17:26  less Makefile
  780  3.2.2013 17:54  cat Makefile                
  776  3.2.2013 17:51  cat ../Makefile
```

To use it, put the appended files to a directory in your `$fpath` and add these lines into your `~/.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:historyevent' command 'fc -dE -lr 1'
zstyle ':completion:*:historyevent' sort no
```

Finally, start a new `zsh` session.

Beware, that's a quick&dirty solution, but it worked well for some time now.

---

**_historyevent**

```
#autoload

local out histevent list expl match desc listargs all nm ret=1

_tags historyevent || return 1

all=(-U)
match="*[[:blank:]]*[[/[:blank:]]$PREFIX*$SUFFIX*"
nm="$compstate[nmatches]"

out=( "${(@f)$(_call_program historyevent fc -l 2>/dev/null)}" )
desc="$out[1]"
out=( "${(@M)out[2,-1]:#${~match}}" )

histevent=( "${(@)${(@M)out##[^0-9]#[0-9]#}##*[[:blank:]]}" )

if zstyle -T ":completion:${curcontext}:historyevent" verbose; then
  list=( "${(@Mr:COLUMNS-1:)out}" )
  desc=(-ld list)
else
  desc=()
fi

_wanted processes expl 'history event' \
    compadd "$@" "$desc[@]" "$all[@]" -a - histevent && ret=0

if [[ -n "$all" ]]; then
  zstyle -s ":completion:${curcontext}:historyevent" insert-ids out || out=menu

  case "$out" in
  menu)   compstate[insert]=menu ;;
  single) [[ $compstate[nmatches] -ne nm+1 ]] && compstate[insert]= ;;
  *)      [[ ${#:-$PREFIX$SUFFIX} -gt ${#compstate[unambiguous]} ]] &&
              compstate[insert]=menu ;;
  esac
fi

return ret
```

**_fc**

```
#compdef fc

local curcontext="$curcontext" line state ret=1

_arguments -C \
   '-e[editor command]' \
   '-l[list last history events]' \
   '-n[suppress numbers]' \
   '-r[reverse order]' \
   '*:history event:->historyevent' && ret=0

if [[ -n "$state" ]]; then
  _alternative \
    'historyevent:: _historyevent' && ret=0
fi

return ret
```